# Change sentiment of a single word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I've been working with NLTK in Python for a few days for sentiment analysis and it's a wonderful tool. My only concern is the sentiment it has for the word 'Quick'. Most of the data that I am dealing with has comments about a certain service and MOST refer to the service as being 'Quick' which clearly has Positive sentiments to it. However, NLTK refers to it as being Neutral. I want to know if it's even possible to retrain NLTK to now refer to the Quick adjective as having positive annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. Found the vader Lexicon file in AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\sentiment. Going through the file I found that the word Quick wasn't even in it. The format of the file is as following:

Token Mean-sentiment StandardDeviation [list of sentiment score collected from 10 people ranging from -4 to 4]

I edited the file. Zipped it. Now NLTK refers to Quick as having positive sentiments.

Comment: I think it should be clearly stated that **this is a dirty hack**

Comment: I suppose so. But the word 'Quick' wasn't even used in the Vader Lexicon file. For domain oriented work, such a hack could be necessary. I did follow procedure and averaged the score collected from 10 random people.

Answer (score 2):

The models used for sentiment analysis are generally the result of a machine-learning process. You can produce your own model by running the model creation on a training set where the sentiments are tagged the way you like, but this is a significant undertaking, especially if you are unfamiliar with the underpinnings.

For a quick and dirty fix, maybe just make your code override the sentiment for an individual word, or (somewhat more challenging) figure out how to change its value in the existing model.  Though if you can get a hold of the corpus the NLTK maintainers trained their sentiment analysis on and can modify it, that's probably much simpler than figuring out how to change an existing model.  If you have a corpus of your own with sentiments for all the words you care about, even better.

In general usage, "quick" is not superficially a polarized word -- indeed, *"quick and dirty"* is often vaguely bad, and a *"quick assessment"* is worse than a *thorough* one; while of course in your specific context, a service which delivers quickly will dominantly be a positive thing. There will probably be other words which have a specific polarity in your domain, even though they cannot be assigned a generalized polarity, and vice versa -- some words with a polarity in general usage will be neutral in your domain. Thus, training your own model may well be worth the effort, especially if you are exploring utterances in a very specific register.

Comment: The quick and dirty method is something I have considered but it'll be largely problematic in the sense that records that have more going on than just a comment on the "quickness" will all be ignored and be labelled inaccurately.

I would like to avoid training my own model as I am already largely limited in training sets and the outcome performance would be decidedly much worse. I was hoping for a way to TWEAK the already trained NLTK in order to carter to this just one need. Perhaps making changes in the lexicon could work?

Comment: And even though I wouldn't know how to go about it. (unfamiliar with the underpinnings)

I still really appreciate your input. I would upvote if I could.

Comment: NLTK is fairly modular, you would need to find the build script for the sentiment analysis model for English (which might be external to NLTK) and run it with a new corpus, or a tweaked one.  If the corpus already contains a significant amount of "quick" occurrences, just add tags to those and retrain.

Comment: It probably works on the level of utterances, though (haven't looked) and if so, you have to be careful to tag as positive only utterances with "quick" which actually are positive, or maybe remove all the utterances with "quick" which are tagged as negative (and perhaps then introduce "interesting" / pesky new biases).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution to my problem. Please do give it a look.